Thunderbolt Dock ethernet connection doesn't work but everything else does
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 and have a Lenovo ThinkPad thunderbolt dock. For some reason my ethernet connection is not working despite all the other devices plugged into the device working fine. Here is what NetworkManager is giving me:
enp109s0: using connection 'Wired connection 1'
enp109s0: connecting (prepare)
enp109s0: connecting (configuring)
enp109s0: connecting (getting IP configuration)
enp109s0: connection failed
enp109s0: disconnected

